# Do class D headphone amplifier ICs typically contain integrated step-down converters?

Tags: digital-logic, audio, analog, circuit-design

Headphones can range in impedance from 8 ohms to a couple hundred ohms, and many only require a few milliwatts. This means that - for a low impedance headphone - only a few hundred mV RMS will be needed at the output.

Typically a class D headphone amplifier IC will be used with a supply voltage of 1.8V to 3.3V. I'm confused about how this high supply voltage is used to drive an appropriate voltage level on the headphones without making one of 2 concessions:

1. The headphone amp includes a voltage regulator inside of it that will supply the voltage rail for the output driver with a lower voltage.
2. Less than 100% of the available "duty cycle swing" is used in the amplifier.

My questions:

- Is something ACTUALLY being done inside the class D amplifiers to bring down the voltage delivered to the headphones, or is it not that high?
- If the voltage does need to be brought down, am I correct in assuming that at least one of these 2 things has to be done internally inside the headphone amp IC to bring it down, or are there other ways?

I'm not asking for information about how to use a headphone amplifier IC; I want to know how a class D amplifier designer would practically deal with a super-low power output requirement that a low-impedance in-ear earbud would present.

Comment: A Diodes Inc Class D is rated for 8R to about 1.5W @ 5.5V max so with 32R it may be about 1/4 of this.  If you have a larger supply then it must be reduced. It also operates down to 2.8V @ 0.5W  @ 0.5% THD. PAM8302A. $5.71 for the PCB

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for information about the design of the amplifier itself, not how to use one in a design.

Comment: The design kits tell it all with the data sheet. The chip uses all of the supply voltage to switch an LC filter to the load,

Comment: Can you give me an example of a datasheet that would give that sort of info? I've looked at a few datasheets. For instance, the DS for Maxim's MAX9879 only shows 2 buffers connected to the headphones; the DS for TI's TPA2054D4A just shows 2 buffers with a mysterious arrow labelled "headphone power limiter".

Comment: What is your input Analog or Dig., and output Z ?

Comment: I want to make a headphone driver that takes PWM directly from a microcontroller and burns off as little extra power as possible, probably delivering ~10mW while only taking 12 or 13mW from a 3.3V power supply.

Comment: That ought to be the essence of your question. Specs affect design choices incl TBD headphone impedance ...the rest is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

Headphone drivers (Class D or otherwise) for portables are limited in swing by the power supply. They do however use a few tricks to achieve greater loudness:

- (more expensive ones) full H-bridge drive
- (cheaper ones) common-mode bass drive

To answer your voltage-conversion question, Class-D drivers use a kind of PWM-to-analog conversion that basically behaves similarly to a step-down DC-DC. As you might infer, being step-down-like means the voltage swing can't be greater than the supply, and it can of course be much lower depending on the signal level.

That said, for your application, consider the common-bass type with analog drive. Class D at the 1-10mW level will not be that efficient.

As far as the headphone impedance, in the big picture, it's more cost-effective to just specify the right impedance for the application. 32 ohms is pretty standard now, and 8 or even 4 ohms are available. The exact impedance isn't so important, so long as the headphone sensitivity is adequate to get the sound pressure level (SPL) needed for listening. That's not such a difficult problem.

Some more background here: https://www.headphonesty.com/2019/04/headphone-impedance-demystified/

And why are there such things as 120 or even 600 ohm headphones? Answer: vacuum tubes. Tubes have high characteristic impedance, so making the headphone load also high impedance avoids the need for a transformer, which reduces cost and (possibly) improves fidelity.

Related but unrelated, let me talk about cars for a moment. The reason why will become apparent shortly.

How do high-power Class D amplifiers for cars achieve such high power (multiple KW) from just +12V? The amplifier has a built-in *boost converter* to make the higher voltage, which then is fed to the amplifier driver stages.

This same voltage-boost approach could be used to make a driver that could handle a wider range of headphone impedances, although on a smaller scale.

This driver uses a scaled boost voltage: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/audio/MAX98390.html

Here's another: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa2013d1.pdf

I haven't seen the next logical step: merging boost conversion to Class D in one stage. I suppose it's possible - modulate a pair of boost DCDC and AC-couple the output. Product idea? Research project?

Comment: Boost + class-D in a single stage is definitely do-able. I did some work a few years ago on a design for a piezo driver which ran from a 2-cell Li-Ion supply. Used a PIC24 to PWM at a few kHz to produce a reasonably clean-ish sine wave output at around 400Hz & 100Vpk.

Answer (score 0):

A Diodes Inc Class D is rated for 8R to about 1.5W @ 5.5V max so with 32R it may be about 1/4 of this.  If you have a larger supply then it must be reduced

It also operates down to 2.8V @ 0.5W  @ 0.5% THD. Or 0.1W @ 0.1%
PAM8302A. $5.71 for the PCB Adafruit

Another example which shows power vs THD vs load R

https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3006/MAX98357A-MAX98357B.pdf